# Linux empty buffer cache command permission denied

Tags: linux, centos, memory, command-line-interface, cache

I'm using the following commands to flush cache:

```
# sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
# sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
# sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

When I use one of the above commands, I get the following:

```
-bash: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
```

My system  running CentOS 6.5, I logged in as root via SSH.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check what you're typing? It appears as though you've used a ';' where a '>' should be and are trying to execute `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'.

Comment: Two questions: why do you need to drop your cache? Second, why are you signing in via ssh as root?

Comment: Third question: is this a OpenVZ VPS?

Comment: Yes it is OpenVZ. My VPS always running out of memory and goes down. I have 1024 MB memory, hosting 4 websites. They are all inactive and don't have any visits, but when I decide to open WHMCS back-end in one of the websites, the VPS goes down after couple of minutes. Rest other websites are static pages only. That's why I need to find a way to free up some memory. @EEAA

Comment: This would not solve the problem, even if you could do it. It would only make matters even worse.

Answer (score 1):

Your CentOS is most likely running as an OpenVZ container and as such you don't have access to the host's `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`.